Karuta discord bot card text detection
There’s a bot on Discord called Karuta that generates an image with 3 or 4 cards. I’m trying to extract all the information from these cards. I’ve made significant progress, but sometimes the results are quite inaccurate. I’m looking for help to make this process much more accurate. An example is provided below.
Karuta card
I am using Tesseract OCR, tesseract.js and sharp for image preprocessing. Here is my code:
import sharp from "sharp";
import Tesseract, { PSM } from "tesseract.js";
import probe from "probe-image-size";
import { corrections } from "./corrections.js";

const cardData = {
    cardWidth: 229,
    cardHeight: 353,
    spaceLength: 45,
};

const workerText = await Tesseract.createWorker("eng", 1);
workerText.setParameters({
    tessedit_char_whitelist:
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz&é0123456789():.,'/-!?; ",
    user_defined_dpi: "1000",
    tessedit_pageseg_mode: PSM.SINGLE_BLOCK, 
});

export async function scrape(url: string) {
    const start = {
        left: 30,
        width: 228,
        top: 35,
        height: 353,
    };
    const image = await fetch(url).then((r) => r.arrayBuffer());

    let nCards = (await probe(url)).width > 900 ? 4 : 3;

    const cards = [];

    const buffers = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < nCards; i++) {
        let card = await sharp(image)
            .extract(start)
            .greyscale()
            .png()
            .toBuffer();

        let top = await sharp(card)
            .extract({
                left: 30,
                width: 167,
                top: 27,
                height: 42,
            })
            .extend({
                top: 10,
                bottom: 10,
                left: 10,
                right: 11,
                background: { r: 255, g: 255, b: 255 },
            })
            .resize(1000)
            .threshold(120)
            .png()
            .toBuffer();

        let bottom = await sharp(card)
            .extract({
                left: 23,
                width: 183,
                top: 278,
                height: 47,
            })
            .extend({
                top: 10,
                bottom: 10,
                left: 10,
                right: 10,
                background: { r: 255, g: 255, b: 255 },
            })
            .resize(1000)
            .threshold(110)
            .png()
            .toBuffer();

        let t = await workerText.recognize(top);

        let b = await workerText.recognize(bottom);

        cards.push({
            top: t.data.words
                .map((w) => w.text.replace(/(?<=\w)R/g, "k"))
                .join(" "),
            bottom: b.data.words
                .map((w) => w.text.replace(/(?<=\w)R/g, "k"))
                .join(" ")
        });

        buffers.push({
            top: top,
            bottom: bottom
        })

        start.left += cardData.spaceLength + cardData.cardWidth;
    }

    return {
        no_cards: nCards,
        cards,
        buffers
    };
}

As said, this works fairly well. However at times there are issues, sometimes ' isn't recognised, or some characters are completely wrong.
Thanks
